# How do I determine which processes are accessing a usb device?

Tags: usb, ups

It seems communication to the USB UPS device is being intermittently interrupted or blocked.  I am getting this errors:

```
pal[17421]: [HidDevice::claim] Failed to disconnect device '/dev/bus/usb/001/003'

pal[17421]: [HidManager::updateDevices] Failed to claim Device '/dev/bus/usb/001/003'

kernel: [ 9997.165994] usb 1-4.4: usbfs: process 15320 (pald) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

I would like to kill any processes that might be attempting to monitor or indicate about that device. For example, I know xfce4-power-manager is running, but killing just that doesn't seem resolve the issue.

For Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64, how can I list all processes that are accessing usb device 003 on bus 001?

Or perhaps maybe a different approach:

For this Ubuntu 16.04 installation running xfce4-desktop, there appears to be a power indicator, a power manager plug-in, and a power notifier on the panel.

Given no other additionally installed packages, by default, what all processes monitor and indicate about uninterruptible power supplies?

Comment: `lsof` command lists processes and which files they open, so if your USB device is flash drive - that's easy, just filter output of `lsof` with `grep` and mountpoin of your USB drive. I often do that if something blocks unmounting USB drive. If your device isn't a storage device, then it's tricky, in theory possible to traverse `/proc` directory and see which file descriptors are open, but that's just a theory. Let me know if you want this as actual answer rather than comment

Comment: As stated, it is a usb ups, so not a storage device.  I was hoping not to have to look at every process if I didn't have to, as there are many. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by removing the battery panel plugins, notifiers, indicators as well as native battery power management.

Note that using the third party UPS management solution was necessary for my case, but generally Ubuntu provides good options as well.

Contention for the hid device was corrected by doing the following:

disable upower
    sudo apt-get remove upower --purge

disable indicator power backend
    sudo vi /usr/share/upstart/sessions/indicator-power.conf

change
    exec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service

to
    #exec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service

remove unneeded packages
    sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

reboot.

This allows the tripplite poweralert daemon to communicate properly with the UPS.

Also, for reference, it is possible that during contention before the native power services are disabled that the power alert console is left in a corrupt state.

This is corrected by:

stop the power alert daemon:
sudo killall -9 pald

Deleting the dat files from:
/var/tripplite/poweralert/data/

Restart or daemonize pald as you choose.
The java app should now run correctly and connect every time.

Hopefully this helps somebody some day.
-c